# different filepaths for html files in same directory

Tags: html, directory

im currently doing a small html project, I have a directory structure that looks like this
[image]

Now, in each of the html files, I want to reference the png file with the corresponding name.
In the frb190711.html file, this looks like this:

```
<img src="../../FRB190711/FRB190711host.png" style="width:550px; object-fit: cover;">
```

Which works as it should, the correct image is diplayed. But when I use the same approach for frb190611, in this manner:

```
    <img src="../../FRB190611/FRB190611host.png" style="width:550px; object-fit: cover;">
```

Then the picture is empty, and if I click the filepath, it leads me to a empty page.
After fiddling with it for a bit, I use another pair of ".." to go up another parent directory

```
 <img src="../../../FRB190611/FRB190611host.png" style="width:550px; object-fit: cover;">
```

and now all of the sudden this works!
This is very strange to me since the two html files are in the same position relative to the picture files. What is causing this?

Comment: Did you post the right example snippets? I don't see a difference between the 2nd and 3rd one.

Comment: it is changed now, the issue at hand is the same as described though

Comment: From FRB, please post the output of "dir /s" (if you're on Windows) or "ls -R" (if on Linux/Mac)